# Database.insert() for single sObject not returning an array of Database.SaveResults

Tags: database.insert

The SFDC documentation says for Database.insert: "If only one sObject is passed in, the SaveResult array contains a single element." However, in my testing, if you pass in a single sObject, you get a single SaveResult, not an array of SaveResult objects. If I pass in a list of sObjects, I do get an array of SaveResult objects back. In other words, according to the documentation, I should always get an array of SaveResult objects back, regardless of whether I pass in a single sObject or a list of sObjects.

Sample Code:

```
List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();
Account acct1 = new Account(name='Test Account1');
Account acct2 = new Account(name='Test Account2');
accts.add(acct1);
accts.add(acct2);
List<Database.SaveResult> result = Database.insert(acct1, false);
system.debug(result);
```

When I execute this code, I get the following:

Error: Illegal assignment from Database.SaveResult to List<Database.SaveResult>

If I change line 6 to:

```
Database.SaveResult result = Database.insert(acct1, false);
```

I get the following result:

Database.SaveResult[getErrors=();getId=0018b00001ugRkvAAE;isSuccess=true;]

Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Reference Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_saveresult

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. The documentation is implying that if you pass a single sObject, you are doing so within a list. There are two basic types of insert for Database.insert(): one taking a list of sObjects and another a single sObject. If you pass in a single sObject, you get back a single SaveResult. If you pass in a list of sObjects, then you get an array of SaveRsult objects back. Their description of the SaveResult class for one sObject confused me.

Comment: You should look at `Database` class in `System` namespace. There you'll find that there are indeed two methods with the same name, the [first one](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_insert) takes a single record and returns a single SaveResult, the [second one](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_insert_2) takes a list of records and returns a list of SaveResult